# replace specific groups of characters with preg_replace

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I have some strings that I need to be able to replace based on a specific pattern. What i have is not working.

I want "OAK", 3 digits, and a letter and disregard the rest

```
$str = "OAK248B1LB";
$regex = "/[^OAK\d{3}[a-z]{1}]/i";
echo "STR: $str<br>";

$str = preg_replace($regex,"",$str);
echo "STR IS NOW: $str <br>";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```
$str = "OAK248B1LB";
$regex = '/^(OAK\d{3}[A-Za-z]).*$/';
$str = preg_replace($regex, "$1", $str);
//=> OAK248B
```

i.e. group the string you want to keep in `$1` and in the replace part use `$1` to discard the rest.

You can use `preg_match` also

```
$str = "OAK248B1LB";
if (preg_match('/^OAK\d{3}[A-Za-z]/', $str, $m) )
   echo $m[0];  //=> OAK248B
```